# Can't use 256-bits counter in AES.MODE_CTR cipher in python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, aes, pycrypto

guys. I use `crypto` library for AES encryption and decryption. AES-128 works perfect:

```
ctr = Counter.new(128)
key = os.urandom(16)
obj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)
```

But when I change 128 to 256, and 16 to 32 error occurs:
`ValueError: unsupported format character 'b' (0x62) at index 29`
Could you help me, any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The counter size is the same as the block size of the block cipher. The block size and key size of a cipher are not directly related.

Now AES-256 has a *key size* of 256 bit and a *block size* of 128 bits. Rijndael, of which AES is a subset, *can* have a block size of 256 bit. But AES, using a key size of 128, 192 or 256 bits, will still have a block size of precisely 128 bits. And that's just because it has been defined that way.

So basically you should always leave `ctr` to `Counter.new(128)`. If you want to use AES-256, increase your `key` to 32 bytes using `os.urandom(32)`.

---

If you want to have hints on how to use / format the counter, please take a look at [NIST SP 800-38A, Appendix B](https://dx.doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-38A).

Comment: yeah, quite fast. Maybe you know, why I get same eror, when I set `initial_value` of `Counter` to `big_endian_to_int(os.urandom(32))`

Comment: Am I right, that initial_value in `Counter` doesn't matter for encryption and decryption. I mean we can use different counters for encrypt/decrypt.

Comment: No that would be extremely wrong. Note that counter mode doesn't perform integrity checks and doesn't pad/unpad. Which means it *always* decrypts, just to the wrong value. The counters must be identical for the same location within the message.

Comment: @AverinMaxim Did you read the answer above?  The counter must always be the same size as the block size, which, for AES, is always 128 bits.  Any other value won't work.

Comment: Yeah, I presume that `big_endian_to_int` simply returns a value that is too large. Pythons integers are not always 16 bytes I presume, so such code should logically fail. Added link to NIST CTR spec to the answer.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes actually I run 10 000 with different strings and decrypt/encrypt with different counters, and it didn't fail.

Comment: As long as the (initial) counters are **identical for the same message** during encryption and decryption and as long as the counters **do not ever overlap** then you should be golden. Again note that you will **not** get an error message if you use the wrong key or counter value - you will just get an message that differs from the original.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yeah, I don't get errors, but tests are passed. I think I do it in a wrong manner. Could you have a look: https://pastebin.com/XwEtDR3Q ?

Comment: @AverinMaxim theoretically, yes. Currently I'm up to my head in work and I cannot see pastebin from my work location (yet).