# Did I use counter for AES-128 cipher on python right?

Tags: python, security, cryptography, aes

guys. I have a code for encrypting/decrypting passwords and put them into database. As I discovered best practices for AES is to store key and initial_vector for every password. But I wanna get rid of initial_vector and use default one. As I understand we should use same counter for decrypting and encrypting. But I don't use the same, and it works.

```
key = os.urandom(16)

def test(str):
 ctr = Counter.new(128)
 obj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)

 message = str.encode('utf-8')
 ciphertext = obj.encrypt(message)

 ctr2 = Counter.new(128)
 obj2 = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr2)
 ans = obj2.decrypt(ciphertext)
 return ans.decode('utf-8')
```

Questions:

1. Why AES-128 ciphers encrypted/decrypted text successfully? Did I miss
   something in code?
2. Is it secure to use one key for encrypting all
   passwords in database, using AES-128?

Comment: "But I wanna get rid of initial_vector and use default one" - **don't reuse IVs**.

Comment: @user2357112 yeah, I know, that I should use IV for only one pass

Comment: Just pre-pend the IV to the encrypted data for use on decryption, it does not need to be secret.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `password_hash`, `PBKDF2`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: @zaph the problem is to generate passwords fast. Why did attacker get key, when he gets DB, cause key in .env file and DB in saparate AWS cloud

Comment: When using CTR mode is is imperative the same key/counter paid are **never reused**.

Comment: 1. Passwords need to be hashed slowly so that it takes an attacker substantial CPU time to brute force them with a list or frequently used passwords. 2. Passwords need to be one-way, that is the password can not be recovered by anyone, even a server administrator. 3. A typical attacker will gain admin access so any encryption password can also be obtained. 4. Do not underestimate the attackers, they are smart and have substantial experience, they are not a curios teenager

Comment: Keep in mind that securing password access is to protect the users, they expect and deserve a secure implementation.

Comment: @zaph I totally agree with you, but .env file and DB in different clouds, that's why getting one of two things don't give attacker anything.

Comment: 1. Don't underestimate attackers. 2. The passwords should **not** be available to **anyone**, not even the site administrators. 3. If you do not want to follow generally accepted security procedures please such as recommended by NIST tell your users that so they can decide if they should trust your site security.

Answer (score 1):

> Why AES-128 ciphers encrypted/decrypted text successfully? Did I miss something in code?

You created the same counter block twice, because you did not set any initial value. See [the documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pycrypto/Crypto.Util.Counter-module.html) of the Counter class.
You must never ever use CTR mode with the same IV twice. Otherwise anyone knowing one piece of plain text can decrypt every other cipher text.

> Is it secure to use one key for encrypting all passwords in database, using AES-128?

It is usually safe to use one key to encrypt multiple data objects in a database.
But as was already mentioned in the comments. You should never encrypt passwords. Passwords are to be stored in a hashed form, so not even you can be able to read them in plaintext. The prefered function for hashing passwords these days is *scrypt*.

Comment: Note that NIST recommends PBKDF2 and for PHP `password_hash` and `password_verify` are a good choice.

Comment: Yes, they do recommend it. PBKDF2 is okay, but still inferiour to other options like scrypt or Argon2 (the new kid on the block) which are a lot better at slowing down an adversary with specialised hardware.

Comment: @mat yeah, I know, that I shouldn't reuse it, but http://stackoverflow.com/a/43988416/6685275

Comment: I'm not a python expert, but the documentation of the Counter class states, that if use just do `Counter.new(128)` you will always end up with a 128-bit counter with an initial value of 1 (no prefix, no suffix).

Comment: @mat it is absolutely true, when then it was suggested to me from crypto man with huge experience